# Trigger button inside UITextView Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im trying to trigger a button event inside the UITextView on change event

**I tried**

```
-(IBAction)myTextfield:(id)sender
 {
    [self.myButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 }
```

when `NSLog(@"");` the event it will show up in the debugger but it does'nt do anything with the sendAction

Does someone know what im missing or doing wrong
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to trigger a button programmatically, that makes no sense? You can rather invoke the button's method directly, and leave the button handling to the user interface, as it was intended.

Comment: Thats when the user press done on the keyboard it needs to login thats why

Answer (score 0):

Indeed i created a `-(void)myMethod;` and put my code in the this method

```
-(IBAction)myTextfield:(id)sender
{
   [self myMethod];
}
```

Comment: You should call your methods like [self myMethod]; or it won't works.

Answer (score -2):

You must register the action to your button. see the home documents:
UIControl implements this method to send all action messages associated with controlEvents, repeatedly invoking sendAction:to:forEvent: in the process. The list of targets and actions it looks up is constructed from prior invocations of addTarget:action:forControlEvents:.

so you use the addTarget:action:forControlEvents:. to your button ,so it works.